# What is the difference between expression <> and != in Hibernate?

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, hql, expression

Recently I's learning **`Hibernate`** by reading its official guide document, Today I get confused when studying the chapter '**`Expressions`**', all examples in document use '**`<>`**' expression to check it 2 columns are equal instead of '**`!=`**', so I want to ask question what is the difference between '**`<>`**' and '**`!=`**'? and what advantage does '**`<>`**' have?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference.

The SQL standard is actually `<>` for "not equals", but (virtually?) every database allows `!=` as a synonymous operator, because most application languages use `!=`. Hibernate allows it too.

Answer (score 0):

`<>` and `=` are opposites -- `<>` refers to Not Equal.

Comment: Sorry, @user2480596, I mean <> and !=.

Comment: @BradyChu -- those should be equivalent.